# How to move a file when "the folder or a file in it is open in another program"

Tags: windows-7, rename

I am trying to rename a folder, but I'm getting the following error:

```
The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program.
Close the folder or file and try again.
```

How does one figure out what program is causing this problem? I've already closed everything on the server for my user. I don't want to restart the server if I can avoid it.

Comment: One could use [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) first then move or rename the file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/117902/easy-way-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) also check out: [Process Explorer: How to check what process is holding my external disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/98365/process-explorer-how-to-check-what-process-is-holding-my-external-disk)